# why am I getting Invalid hook call error when using react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, render

I have been trying to render these codes, but they do not work, and I get errors,I try different ways, the latest was installing v6 of react-router, I will appreciate if you help me;

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,

} from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home route</h1>
    </div>
  );
}



reportWebVitals();
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.1"

  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

    You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
    You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
    You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

Comment: Can you post your package.json, so we can know which versions of the packages you are using?

Comment: Please replace `Routes` tag with `Switch` tag and everything will be fine.

Comment: it does not work with 'switch'

Comment: @mehdi Please use [edit] to update your question, and don't post an answer :)

Comment: Would you please share the exact error message with us. Because it is working fine here with exact version of packages
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-nluwx